# rtl scroll and navigation in product comparison table

Tags: css, right-to-left

I would create a product comparison table rtl version.
but problem when `direction: rtl;` in css in scroll and navigation.

```
.cd-products-wrapper {
    overflow-x: auto;
    direction:rtl;/* this fixes the buggy scrolling on webkit browsers - mobile devices only - when overflow property is applied */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```

demo : https://codyhouse.co/demo/products-comparison-table/index.html

Comment: You need to explain what that problem is. Now you only have us look at a page and guess...check this first: [repro]